# Get multiple values from a hidden field through Jquery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to use a hidden field control in my in a foreach loop where am binding multiple values in the hidden field value in this way

```
@foreach(var category in Model)
{
<input type="hidden" Id="hdnCategory" value="@category.Id"/>
}
```

Now using Jquery I am trying to retrieve the value. But the result is not as expected. It is actually retrieving the first value from the foreach

```
 function btnClick() {
     var categoryID = $("#hdnCategory").val();      
}
```

This function am calling in a button click in this way

```
<img class="imageclass"src="listofImages" onclick="imageClick()" />
```

Can someone please suggest me where I am going wrong..

Comment: Your every hidden field have same id. Better add class and use in your jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

Also i think your function name is different

```
@foreach(var category in Model)
{
    <input type="hidden" Id="hdnCategory" class="csscategory" value="@category.Id"/>
}

<img class="imageclass" src="listofImages" onclick="imageClick()" />
```

```js
function imageClick() {
    $("input.csscategory").each(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All those hidden fields have the same `id` so jQuery (and also vanilla JavaScript with `querySelector`) just returns the first one.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing tag with ID only first one is fetched because ID is supposed to be unique.

For your code to work change ID attribute to class attribute then loop through elements and fetch value.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="imageclass" src="listofImages" />
<input type="hidden" class="hdnCategory" value="@category.Id" />
<input type="hidden" class="hdnCategory" value="@category.Id2" />...

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.imageclass').click(function() {
              $(".hdnCategory").each(function() {
                  var val = $(this).val();
                  //do some thing with val
                  alert(val);
                });
              });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: fixed syntax and included jquery please check again.